# Adding spring-boot library produce "Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContex"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a single class application

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class);
    }
}
```

It's works pretty well (doing nothing) with the following dependencies (Ivy notation used)

```
    <dependency org="org.springframework.boot" name="spring-boot-starter" rev="1.1.7.RELEASE"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context" rev="4.1.0.RELEASE"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-beans" rev="4.1.1.RELEASE"/>
```

But when I add `<dependency org="org.springframework.boot" name="spring-boot" rev="1.1.7.RELEASE"/>` I get the following exception.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at one.video.streaming.Main.main(Main.java:48)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:136)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 | Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:174)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:147)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/10/10 17:45:49 |       ... 13 common frames omitted
```

My goal is not to add spring-boot library, I don't need it, but I want to understand how does Spring work and why it starts to trying to use some web stuff for my app.

Comment: I think if you look at your classpath you will find some other Spring and Spring Boot dependencies. Maybe something with "web" in the name?

Comment: You are mixing spring versions… 4.1.0 and 4.1.1. I strongly suggest using the spring starters instead of trying to add your own dependency versions, that way you know that you use compatible versions.